# Python Requests: Cannot get post cookies

Tags: python, cookies, request, session-cookies

I'm trying to login to a website which uses recaptcha 2.0. The login is a bit secure but i managed to pass the checks so far.
Basically except captcha and post data it needs an hidden csrf token input and a cookie csrf token, both are needed or it will show a 404.
Now i managed to get those, i'm sending a post request as below

This is the variable which holds a cookie grabbed on the first visit of webpage

Been since last night trying to resolve this issue, when i try to send the data on the second request no cookie comes back

`{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', '__cfduid': 'dfe11fd58412a09b347fcfcc2601584845857460'}`
Now to the actual code:

```
formData = {
            'utf8': '✓',
            'authenticity_token': 'xxx'
            'bb_user[email]': _BBEMAIL,
            'bb_user[password]': _BBPASS,
            'g-recaptcha-response': captcha,
            'bb_user[remember_me]': '1'
        }

cookie = "cookie variable above" #just an edit
        try:
            rp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=formData, allow_redirects=False, cookies=cookie, verify=False, timeout=10)
            cookie_dict = dict(rp.cookies)
            with open(_FILE_PATH, 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(cookie_dict))
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            print '===============login==============',e
            traceback.print_exc()
            return False
```

Im trying to save the cookies for later use by saving them into a file but all i get in the file is {}
Im using 2captcha api to solve the captcha code
Also i know there are similar questions here but no solution seems to work

Comment: i have faced problem with ```data``` parameter in ```requests.post``` before,try changing it to ```params```, and why to use ```cookie``` variable? i think just put it in the```formData```

Comment: i tried using params, it didn't work, just did a print of response and it is showing me invalid credentials
also im using coocies because when you visit login page a cookie is set by the server(csrf cookie) then when you submit data that same cookie needs to be present

Comment: read [this <mayHelp>](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Comment: @MahmoudHossam i managed to fix it somehow, removed dictionaries and went for plain variables, added them to cookie jar, the link above helped alot, thanks
however 1/2 cases i get captcha error or invalid user/pass and i dont understand why, all data is correct

Comment: are you sure you are doing everything right like your browser?_compare using Chrome dev tools_

Comment: @MahmoudHossam i managed to fix it, dumb me, i was based on an old code i found but the form names had changed a bit and it was not working hehe
Thank you for all the help, def helped alot